# Tinymce resize vertical only

Tags: tinymce

Is there anyway to force tinymce to [resize](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_resize_horizontal) vertical only? It breaks my layout when resized horizontal.

So that this works the same as a default textarea `resize: vertical;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use:

```
tinyMCE.init({
            // other stuff...
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,
            theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false                       
    });
```

Comment: Does not work for version 4. Maybe works for older versions, could be specified in the post.

Comment: Not sure about V4 but those options surely are not available or compatible with V5. Biskrem Muhammad answer provides the right information and should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 24):

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  resize: true
});
```

resize option has 3 values:

1. `false`: to disable.
2. `true`: enable only `Vertical` resize
3. `'both'`: enable both resize directions

> check the [Documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#resize)

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: to make it work you have to enable the `statusbar` option, it's enabled by default, but in case if turned it to `statusbar: false` you will have to re-enable it `statusbar: true`

Comment: The `statusbar` bit fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for explaining the additional values accepted by the `resize` option and for providing a link to the official documentation. This one should be the accepted answer.